# How do I fix the units in the legend of this stat_density_2d plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've managed to create my first stat_density_2d plot:

```
ggplot(qual_colleges_all_data_clean, aes(x = UGDS, y = MD_EARN_WNE_P10), alpha = 0.4, size = 0.5) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..level..), geom="polygon") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="lightblue", high="firebrick3") +
  geom_smooth(method="loess", se=TRUE, formula = y~x, color="chartreuse1", fill="darkolivegreen2") +
  labs(title = "Median Earnings By UGDS") +
  scale_colour_hue(h = c(0, 280)) +
  xlab(label = "UGDS") +
  ylab(label = "Median Earnings 10 years After Entry")
```

In my data `UGDS` is a (numeric class) column of integers.

The plot looks fine, but I don't understand why the legend units are given as, e.g., "8e-09". How do I change the legend units to something more readily comprehensible (perhaps "more dense" and "less dense")?

[image]

Here's the `str()`:

```
## tibble [1,121 × 25] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
##  $ UNITID            : num [1:1121] 159009 217721 198862 176406 158802 ...
##  $ INSTNM            : chr [1:1121] "Grambling State University" "Benedict College" "Livingstone College" "Tougaloo College" ...
##  $ SCH_DEG           : num [1:1121] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
##  $ CCBASIC           : num [1:1121] 18 22 22 21 21 22 18 19 19 18 ...
##  $ ADM_RATE          : num [1:1121] 0.972 0.768 0.501 0.707 0.388 ...
##  $ ACTCM25           : num [1:1121] 16 15 14 15 19 14 16 16 15 15 ...
##  $ ACTCM75           : num [1:1121] 20 19 16 22 23 17 19 18 19 19 ...
##  $ SAT_AVG           : num [1:1121] 981 933 854 969 1075 ...
##  $ UGDS              : num [1:1121] 4153 2034 1114 703 1215 ...
##  $ COSTT4_A          : num [1:1121] 25754 27927 28319 22594 31625 ...
##  $ TUITIONFEE_IN     : num [1:1121] 7683 16600 18296 10861 19281 ...
##  $ TUITIONFEE_OUT    : num [1:1121] 16706 16600 18296 10861 19281 ...
##  $ AVGFACSAL         : num [1:1121] 6352 5808 5408 4755 6472 ...
##  $ PFTFAC            : num [1:1121] 0.994 0.719 0.825 0.741 0.593 ...
##  $ RET_FT4           : num [1:1121] 0.744 0.556 0.562 0.73 0.669 ...
##  $ MD_EARN_WNE_P10   : num [1:1121] 33961 30951 30521 33291 37014 ...
##  $ PCT25_EARN_WNE_P10: num [1:1121] 19299 19230 17973 20243 23757 ...
##  $ PCT75_EARN_WNE_P10: num [1:1121] 50236 43045 45132 46866 52462 ...
##  $ MD_EARN_WNE_P6    : num [1:1121] 27399 23174 24630 25088 29132 ...
##  $ GRADS             : num [1:1121] 1079 6 NA 8 NA ...
##  $ RET_FT4_POOLED    : num [1:1121] 0.734 0.56 0.53 0.738 0.678 ...
##  $ C100_4_POOLED     : num [1:1121] 0.105 0.18 0.152 0.22 0.269 ...
##  $ INEXPFTE          : num [1:1121] 3905 4224 5598 4884 7815 ...
##  $ C150_4_POOLED     : num [1:1121] 0.34 0.271 0.239 0.412 0.454 ...
##  $ GRAD_DEBT_MDN     : num [1:1121] 36750 34500 32875 32100 31250 ...
```

Thank you, most sincerely, for any help!

Comment: try options(scipen = 999) in your RStudio and then run your plot again. This should turn off the scientific notation, at least

Comment: @hachiko, sorry but can you expand? Is `options(scipen=999)` something I add to the plot code? Thanks very much for your reply!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change scientific notation on legend labels in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072971/how-to-change-scientific-notation-on-legend-labels-in-ggplot2)

Comment: That is *partially* helpful, @mb158127, but when I added "options(scipen=10000)" to my code, nothing changed. Now, when I added `labels = comma` the legend units changed from scientific notation but to all zeros.

Comment: That is because your values are all approximately 0, as shown by the legend pic you shared. This is why scientific notation was being provided. You should inspect the range of values you are plotting and consider re-scaling them to get to units you prefer, which I assume is probably around 1 billion of whatever units you have currently.

Comment: Hi @RKeithL with options(scipen = 999) you can add that to the top of your project where you might declare libraries or right before the ggplot call. It doesn't live as part of ggplot, but rather is a more global call to turn off the scientific notation in the project. It's helpful in reading p-values that are not scientific notation from the summary(lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)) or other places